# Regex and Map argument matching

Tags: regex, dictionary, elixir, enumerable

While writing a function, I am using argument matching like so:

```
def process_thing( %{} = thing )
```

I'm expecting that `thing` is a Map, and is Enumerable.  Unfortunately, this argument list is also matching Regexes specified as `~r/regex/`, and the Regex (although it returns true for `is_map(~r/thing/)`) is not Enumerable.

How can I craft this function definition so that only Maps - or ideally, Enumerable things - are dispatched to this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to *match* on something being an `Enumerable`. If you're ok with just maps, then you have the [`is_map/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#is_map/1) built-in function:

```
def process_thing(thing) when is_map(thing) do
   ...
end
```

One alternative is checking for all the data types that you expect and support:

```
def process_thing(thing) when is_map(thing) or is_list(thing), do: ...
def process_thing(%MapSet{}), do: ...
...
```

If you need to support *all* enumerables (maybe it will be easier to give good advice with more information on your use case), you can always use [`Protocol.assert_impl!/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Protocol.html#assert_impl!/2):

```
def process_thing(thing) when is_map(thing) or is_list(thing), do: ...
def process_thing(%{__struct__: struct}) do
  assert_impl!(Enumerable, struct)
end
```

and handle the possible failure of `Protocol.assert_impl!/2`. I'm not sure if this implementation is bullet-proof and again, there may be a cleaner way to implement this. :)

One more thing: if you want to match on maps but not match on structs (like `Regex`), one way to solve it is to first match on the things you **don't** want to match so that you get them out of the way (and handle them however you need to):

```
def process_thing(%{__struct__: _}), do: # bad things here, we don't like structs
def process_thing(%{} = thing), do: # hey, that's a map now!
```